# How to put Cursor to intent in Android?

Tags: android

I try to set Cursor to Intent, but I have an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

I try it:

```
Cursor myCursor = ...
intent.putExtra(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_MY_CURSOR, (Serializable) myCursor);
```

What is my problem? 
Thanks you!

Comment: **"What is my problem?"** : Quite simple - a `Cursor` isn't `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor class is not parcelable,  better option will be to create Parcelable entity class which will represent a row in cursor
so one row of cursor is one object of entity. use the

`ArrayList<Entity> to pass using intent intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("name", ArrayList<Entity>)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use Intent with some data, all data is created clone and copied, while Cursor object need to be closed and it is alive.

So you should not use Cursor to send another activity but use ArrayList.